# How to get contacts associated with social media(google,yahoo,...) synced with phone, in android

Tags: android

My issue is, when I'm fetching contacts from phone, it will get all the contacts (from phone, SIM, social accounts etc)

i want to know, if I can get contacts from social accounts separately?

Comment: How its possible, only  two view and votes up is 4 times.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the contacts for the applications are synced, you can query the `RawContacts` (with the `READ_CONTACTS` permission in your manifest) and get them filtered by account type. For example:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
    RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[] { RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY },
    RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ?",
    new String[] { <account type here> },
    null);

ArrayList<String> myContacts = new ArrayList<String>();
int contactNameColumn = c.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY);
while (c.moveToNext())
{
    // You can also read RawContacts.CONTACT_ID to read the
    // ContactsContract.Contacts table or any of the other related ones.
    myContacts.add(c.getString(contactNameColumn));
}
```

It's just a matter of supplying the appropriate account type. For example:

- `"com.google"` for Gmail,
- `"com.whatsapp"` for WhatsApp,
- `"com.skype.contacts.sync"` for Skype,
- &c.

Comment: Thank You for help...:)
can i get contacts, which are not associated any social account...
i mean , just from phone and SIM, though I've synced contacts ??

Comment: @user2192174 There must be an account type associated with them, but I don't know which one it is. You should be able to determine it by modifying this query to NOT filter by account type, and inspect the different account types it contains.